# Python SQLAlchemy relationship set event hook

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

In SQLAlchemy ORM it is possible to hook attribute set event for all tables and columns using this code:

```py
@event.listens_for(Base, 'attribute_instrument')
def configure_listener(class_, key, inst):    
    if not hasattr(inst.property, 'columns'):
        return

    @event.listens_for(inst, "set", retval=True)
    def set_column_value(instance, value, oldvalue, initiator):
        column = inst.property.columns[0]
        # HOOK CODE
        logging.info("%s: %s -> %s" % (inst.property.columns[0], oldvalue, value))
        return value
```

But this approach doesn't suitable for relationships. Table attributes which are relationships don't go through this event while [official guide](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.events.AttributeEvents.set) tells nothing about that relationship's attributes won't be processed by event. So the question: is there any way in SQLAlchemy to hook events coupled with relationship attribute modification?

*Remark*: I hoped because relationships linked with other table by means of foreign key column then modification of this (foreign key) column will generate an event but I have been mistaken: there is true only when record already has valid Id but otherwise (when object has not been added to the database yet) this event not raised.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is now a `init_collection` event in 1.0 sqlalchemy

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/events.html#attribute-events